# Calculate user ranking in search results [Laravel]

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `ranking` module where users can search for other users. The results are displayed in a table, and for each result I want to display the user's current ranking position as well. So for example, when searching for `dav`, the result could be:

```
--  Position   --   Points   --  Name  --
     30              2345         Dave
     105             1650         Davy
     965             895          Superdavy
     1949            35           Dave123
```

My question is: what would be the best way to calculate the positions? Positions are calculated by ordering users by `points`. I can get all the users with

`$results = User::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orderBy('points')->paginate(25);`

But should I loop through the results and query the database for each user to calculate the ranking position? Or is there an easier way? Because, if the search contains 50 results and someone is searching multiple times within seconds, a lot of database queries are fired...

Comment: Please show where is ranking number stored or how do you calculate it.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I updated the answer

Comment: Isn't the position column redundant?

Comment: @BaikHo, yes this column is not part of the database , but it is calculated when displayed on the frontend.

Comment: Recomputing ranking is a costly task when you have lots of items to rank.  Rethink the necessity of doing it in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tens of thousands of users, I guess it's a good idea to use scheduler task which will recalculate current position for every user every hour, for example.

If not, try to calculate position at runtime:

```
$positions = User::orderBy('points', 'desc')->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Pass this variable to the view and display position with:

```
{{ array_search($user->id, $positions) + 1 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that tabular output as shown above by ordering points in descending order so you can get rankings quite nicely.
`$results = User::where('name', 'LIKE',"%$query%")->orderBy('points', 'desc')->paginate(25);`

And yes concept of paginating is good as result can be of any number so you can have control over lots of query execution at the same time.
But you stop caring about number of times they execute query you don't have control over it and you can't control it.
All you can do is some cashing mechanism:

`$results = User::where('name', 'LIKE',"%$query%")->orderBy('points', 'desc')->remember(50)->paginate(25);`

This stores above records in cache so if you try to execute next query it retrieves result of cache instead of firing sql query to database. Or you can use chunks in laravel.
`DB::table('users')->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orderBy('points', 'desc')->chunk(100, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        // here you can use filters
    }
});`

all these can be found in this page of laravel hope this helps you.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries

Comment: But how do I calculate the ranking positions for each user in the search results?

Comment: OK, the problem is to get the position it seems for that what you can do is: `$results = User::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orderBy('points', 'desc')->pluck('name')->toArray();` $position = array_search('name', $results) + 1;`